# Customize the Mflat theme in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a WordPress blog hosted at this URL [www.richintellects.com](http://www.richintellects.com) My website has three tabs, [HOME](http://www.richintellects.com/), [ADVERTISE](http://www.richintellects.com/advertise/) and [ABOUT RICHINTELLECTS](http://www.richintellects.com/about/).
The home page displays all blog posts and from there, one can click on a post heading to view the page for just that one single post.

WHAT I WANT TO DO.
I want to publish posts to the [ADVERTISE](http://www.richintellects.com/advertise/) tab (Not necessarily adverts, just posts). I dont want the posts published to the [ADVERTISE](http://www.richintellects.com/advertise/) tab to appear under the [HOME](http://www.richintellects.com/) tab. So I was hoping there could be a plugin that could allow you to specify which page you want your post to appear on.
Secondly, I want the [ADVERTISE](http://www.richintellects.com/advertise/) page to behave in exactly the same manner as the HOME page in that, upon clicking the [ADVERTISE](http://www.richintellects.com/advertise/) tab, all posts that were planned to appear on that page is displayed as per the HOME page and clicking each of the headings to the posts opens a single post page for that post.

I know that I have to do some hard core to work around this and I only need to understand the framework of the theme to work the magic but then again I thought it would be sweet if there were a plugin to save me the trouble.
I want to get this done cleanly and neatly as I don't want to mess up the configurations that tie my website to Google analytic and other analytic tools.

All advice and help is dearly appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**You got two options:**

**[Option 1]**
Create a custom template and assign it to *Advertise* page. Further copy the index.php code in custom template.
Refer WordPress Codex: [Create Custom page templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates)

**[Option 2]** Hire a developer. ;)

Comment: Thanks 4 your response @Aky Joe. I went with the option to create a custom template thanks to the link you provided. I am however stuck with one simple php loop and was hoping you could help out. I want to make sure posts that fall under a specific category 'Diary' do not show up on the Home page.So i intend to edit this line of code "<?php if(have_posts()) : ?><?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>" to filter out the posts displayed by category and this is what i added " <?php if(have_posts()) : ?><?php while(have_posts()) : ?><?php while(the_category(' | ') != 'Diary') : the_post(); ?>"

Comment: Am sure my addition does not make sense because of the nested whiles or probably i need to do some string conversions before comparing. I kindly need your help to know where and what am doing wrong. thanks.

Comment: How about this?" <?php if(have_posts()) : ?><?php while(have_posts()) : ?><?php while( strcmp(the_category() != 'Diary')) : the_post(); ?> " Would it work?

Comment: You will have to fire a **custom WP_query()**. Try something like this below

`$query = new WP_Query( 'cat=-12,-34,-56' );` 
P.S=> Minus (-) sign states the category id which you wish to exclude from the query. So, find out the category id of diary and prefix a minus sign. It should work.